# Making a form must have at least 1 field required

Tags: php, html

Good day everyone I have the following form in my project that allows the user to update/edit their information
[image]

Currently all fields are required before submitting the form, I want to make it that it should have at least 1 field submitted(doesn't matter which one)
The only solution I thought about is that I drop the required="" and on form submit I check them manually using if(isset(fieldname)), is there a better solution than this or I am in the right path?

Comment: you are on right path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check the posted data u can use [isset()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

```
if(!isset($firstname) || trim($firstname) == '')
{
   echo $msg = "You did not fill out the required fields.";
}
```

Comment: So it is just like I stated in the question, okay solution accepted, thanks.